# What's ASP FormCollection field's base, on html inputs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I confuse input's Id, Name, Value and other custom attribute that how **`FormCollection`** is created from them. My questions are:

1. **`FormCollection`** keys are created from input's Id or Name?
2. Are Value of `input` same as `formCollection[key]`?
3. Can we Get other input custom attribute from **`FormCollection`**?

Comment: Forms post back `name/value` pairs based on a controls `name` and `value` attributes. A controls `id` attribute is not submitted (nor are any other attributes). And you should not be using `FormCollection` - post back and bind to your model!

Comment: My data in form is full dynamic and it created runtime. So I don't have any info about them. So I can't use ViewModel. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FormCollection keys are created from input's Id or Name?

They are created from `name`.

> Are Value of input same as formCollection[key]?

A `FormCollection` have the list of `input` from the `form`, the `key` is the `name` of the `input`. You acces the `value` by input `name`.

> Can we Get other input custom attribute from FormCollection?

With `FormCollection` you only have acces to `name` and `value`.

---

Instead of `FormCollection` you should create your own model. This way you can *validate* your data more easier and you don't have to know the `name` of the input to take the value.

```
class MyModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    //other validation/UI helpers attributes
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(MyModel model) 
{ 
    /* body */ 
}
```

---

If you want to use a model and the content is created dynamic, you can give names to inputs the model binder undestand, as presented below

```
<input type="text" name="Prop1" ... />
<input type="text" name="Prop2" ... />
```

This will bind to model automarically. Although the validation will be only on server side in this case.

Comment: My data in form is full dynamic and it created runtime. So I don't have any info about them. So I can't use ViewModel. thx

Comment: @SiamakFerdos If you know how the **Model Binding** works you can create the name of the inputs so you can use a ViewModel. Or you can create your custom model binder.

Comment: I create a custom grid. I use a pair of the in a page. I want get all rows of one grid. user can move rows between two grid on client side. So, First: I don't know about inputs that are in grid, Second: I don't know which row are moved and I should bind it to model Third: This grid is a project on a other web solution. I create it for all type of web projects. So I can't use Model at all